# C# Lighting Model Problems

Tags: c#, graphics, lighting

I am trying to create a graphics lighting model that applies diffuse, ambient and specular effects to objects constructed from points and vectors.

So far i have managed to calculate the normal vectors by performing a crossproduct of two vectors. I don't know if these need to be normalised as well?

I have created the diffuse, ambient and specular methods from equations but do not know how to implement them

I have set a light vector at `(0, 0, -1)`, should this be normalised?

I do not know how to generate the light so it effects the object. How do you change the colour with results from the diffuse/ambient/specular equations?

A step by step guide on how to do this would be amazing.

Comment: Probably should mention what graphics framework you're using.  WPF? OpenTK? XNA?

Comment: ...what have you actually done so far, maybe include some of the code you already have

Comment: I am using no graphics framework, this is from scratch all coded from scratch.

Comment: so far i can represent objects from text files using x,y,z points and vertices, i am now trying to add a lighting model but am struggling to figure out how to implement the light source and what vectors normalise and how to get the normal vectors and how the light changes the color

Comment: Judging by the way you've written the question I'd guess you're trying to bite off much more than you can chew :) Even if you want to create this from scratch get yourself a ready-made framework, learn how it works first. There's too much wheel to reinvent here

Comment: thanks, Yea its pretty tricky, but the challenge is fun, ive got all the normals working correctly now. Just need to figure out how to change the color using the results from the diffuse/ambient/specular equations. and does any one know what the vector for the viewer would be?